# How do you avoid starting a relationship with a crewmate?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I'm preparing a Mass Effect 2 save to import to Mass Effect 3, and I'd like to ensure I avoid starting a relationship as a male Shepard while still keeping things friendly with my crewmates.

In Mass Effect, there were particular dialogue choices you could take to achieve this - are there similar choices in Mass Effect 2?

Answer (score 4):

If you're not interested in romancing a character, there's a simple solution - never talk to them.

More helpfully, you can never "accidentally" commit to a relationship. You always have a choice. Most of these relationships can be kept "open" (i.e., still possible, the next time you speak with them) with the *exception* of Miranda. Yvonne Strahovski doesn't like being lead on, apparently.  Here's a quote from the [Mass Effect Wikia](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance#Mass_Effect_2). Male shepherd only, unfortunately.

> For a male Shepard, a love interest is "locked in" once you express
>   interest at the following dialogue points:
>
> Jack: "I want to talk about us." To prevent locking-in, say "Never
>   mind".
>
> Tali: "I want to talk about you." at the point where she beckons you
>   toward the drive core. To prevent locking-in, say "So you're not
>   interested?" followed by "I need to think about this."
>
> Miranda: "Can we talk?" at the point where she says "I don't know what
>   this is, if it's just stress, or blowing off steam, or..." you can not
>   opt out; every option results in either becoming locked-in, or the
>   relationship being broken off permanently. Hope you saved before the
>   conversation!

Comment: Thanks for the input.  For completion's sake, is there any information on avoiding becoming "locked in" for female Shepards?

Comment: @Teryx - I didn't see it when browsing the ME wiki, and I'm not in a position to be able to test in my own games. If someone else has access to that info, however, I'll gladly add it in.